# Pulumi - S3 - How can I attach a AccesspointPolicy to a Accesspoint when the policy depends on it

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, pulumi

I know I can create a Accesspoint and attach a policy like this:

```
exampleAccessPoint, err := pulumiS3.NewAccessPoint(ctx, accessPointName, &pulumiS3.AccessPointArgs{
        AccountId: pulumi.String(exampleAcc),
        Bucket:    pulumi.String(exampleBucket),
        Name:      pulumi.String(exampleName),
        Policy: pulumi.String(policy)
})
```

but what do I do when my policy looks like this:

```
policyDoc := policyDocument{
        Version: "2012-10-17",
        Statement: []statementEntry{
            {
                Effect: "Allow",
                Action: []string{
                    "s3:GetObject",
                },
                Resource:  []string{exampleAccesspointArn},
                Principal: struct{ AWS []string }{exampleValue},
            },
            {
                Effect:    "Allow",
                Action:    []string{"s3:ListBucket"},
                Resource:  []string{accessPointArn},
                Principal: struct{ AWS []string }{exampleValue},
                Condition: &condition{
                    StringLike: &stringLike{
                        S3Prefix: examplePrefix,
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

It depends on the accessPointArn so I can't attach it on creation, so what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulumi has a special type called [Output](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/concepts/inputs-outputs) that's made for managing resource relationships like these. Since your policy depends on the resource ARN, and the ARN won't be available until after the `AccessPoint` is created, you'll need to construct the policy as a string *output* (rather than just a plain string) by "waiting" for the ARN to be available using `.ApplyT()`.

Here's a somewhat simplified version of your example showing how you might do that:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"

    "github.com/pulumi/pulumi-aws/sdk/v6/go/aws/s3"
    "github.com/pulumi/pulumi/sdk/v3/go/pulumi"
)

func main() {
    pulumi.Run(func(ctx *pulumi.Context) error {

        bucket, err := s3.NewBucket(ctx, "bucket", nil)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        accessPoint, err := s3.NewAccessPoint(ctx, "access-point", &s3.AccessPointArgs{
            Bucket: bucket.ID(),
        })
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        policy, err := s3.NewBucketPolicy(ctx, "policy", &s3.BucketPolicyArgs{
            Bucket: bucket.ID(),

            //  Use .ApplyT() to wait for the ARN to be available, then compose a new string output with it.
            Policy: accessPoint.Arn.ApplyT(func(arn string) (pulumi.StringOutput, error) {
                p, err := json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": []map[string]interface{}{
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
                            "Principal": map[string]string{
                                "AWS": "exampleValue",
                            },

                            //  Use the unwrapped string.
                            "Resource": arn + "/*", 
                        },
                    },
                })

                if err != nil {
                    return pulumi.StringOutput{}, err
                }

                //  Return a new, transformed string output.
                return pulumi.String(p).ToStringOutput(), nil 
            }).(pulumi.StringOutput),
        })
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        ctx.Export("policy", policy.ID())
        return nil
    })
}
```

This tells Pulumi to create the `AccessPoint` first, then the `BucketPolicy`. If the policy happened to call for multiple values from multiple resources, you could use [`.All()`](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/concepts/inputs-outputs/all/) instead.

That's the general pattern, though: use `.ApplyT()` to receive and transform a plain value into a new output, then pass the transformed output as an *input* to another resource. The docs go into this in much more detail:

- https://www.pulumi.com/docs/concepts/inputs-outputs/apply/
- https://www.pulumi.com/docs/concepts/inputs-outputs/all/

Hope that helps!